# Fill numpy array with other numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, numpy

I have following numpy arrays:

```py
    whole = np.array(
        [1, 0, 3, 0, 6]
    )

    sparse = np.array(
        [9, 8]
    )
```

Now I want to replace every zero in the **whole** array in chronological order with the items in the **sparse** array. In the example my desired array would look like:

```py
    merged = np.array(
        [1, 9, 3, 8, 6]
    )
```

I could write a small algorithm by myself to fix this but if someone knows a time efficient way to solve this I would be very grateful for you help!

Comment: Are you sure the number of `0`s match with the `sparse`?

Comment: ...since you could just write `whole[whole==0] = sparse` then

Comment: Yes! Awesome, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you assume that sparse has the same length as there is zeros in whole ?

If so, you can do:

```
import numpy as np
from copy import copy

whole = np.array([1, 0, 3, 0, 6])
sparse = np.array([9, 8])

merge = copy(whole)
merge[whole == 0] = sparse
```

if the lengths mismatch, you have to restrict to the correct length using len(...) and slicing.

Comment: I was outdated by the comment above, but my method doesn't change 'whole' array in place.

Comment: Would it be inplace without the copy? I am a little confused about the purpose of the copy.

Comment: You should use numpy's copy as opposed to `copy.copy`

Comment: To Kevin : if I don't use copy, when I update 'merge', the original array  'whole' is modified the same way'. So one has to copy the numpy array to keep the original data